# Mathematical structures with a canonical partial order

Tags: order-theory

I like order theory very much, and am always excited to discover mathematical structures that can be intrinsically endowed with a partial order. "Easy" examples are $T_0$ topological spaces (with $x \leqslant y \Leftrightarrow x \in \overline{\{y \}}$) and vector spaces endowed with a pointed convex cone $C$ (with $x \leqslant y \Leftrightarrow y - x \in C$). A bit less straightforward is the fact that an inverse semigroup is a partially ordered set with $x \leqslant y \Leftrightarrow \exists e, e^2 = e, x = ye$.

Would you have other such examples?

Thank you.

Edit: I am not looking for examples of partially ordered sets, neither for examples where a partial order can be obviously defined; the example of inverse semigroups gives a good idea to the kind of answers I would love to have: once one gets the definition of an inverse semigroup this is not at all obvious that a partial order compatible with the algebraic structure can be defined and lead to fruitful discoveries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are those things called power sets (or more general arbitrary sets of sets). The subset relation defines a very canonical partial order.

If you have already a partially ordered set $P$ and an arbitrary set $X$ then the set of functions $X\to P$ can be equipped with a partial order by
$$f\le g \text{ iff } \forall x\in X \:\:f(x)\le g(x).$$

Comment: Well, this is not really the kind of (straightforward) examples I am looking for. Maybe I need to make my question more specific.